# How to find all points of discontinuities of $f(x)=\lfloor{\cos{x}\rfloor}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

How to find all points of discontinuities of $f(x)=\lfloor{\cos{x}\rfloor}$

Please help me.I am unable to determine the points of discontinuities.

I know that

$\lfloor\cos x\rfloor =\cases{ 1,& cos x=1 \cr 0,& 1>cos x>0\cr -1,& cos x <0 }$

Comment: Drawing the graph of the function may be a nice start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos 0 = 1$. $0 \leq \cos x < 1$ for all $0 < x \leq \pi/2$; so $\lfloor \cos x \rfloor = 0$ on the half open interval $]0, \pi/2]$. $-1 \leq \cos x < 0$ for all $\pi/2 < x < 3\pi/2$; so $\lfloor \cos x \rfloor = -1$ on the open interval $]\pi/2, 3\pi/2[$. $0 \leq \cos x < 1$ for all $3\pi/2 \leq x < 2\pi$; so $\lfloor \cos x \rfloor = 0$ on $[3\pi/2, 2\pi[$. Note that the cosine function is periodic with the period $2\pi$.